# Where to define custom entity caching rules of detail pages

Tags: entities, caching, 9

When you have a larger project you probably have both internal page cache as internal dynamic page cache module enabled. In my case I do.
But I have a section on my website containing custom entities ('Contest') where I would like to have custom-tailored control of caching of the detail page (contest/1). This is what I found so far:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view_alter()
 * Disable caching on all contest entity types
 */
function mymodule_entity_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  $types = ['contest'];
  if (in_array($entity->bundle(), $types)) {
    $build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
    \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
  }
}
```

Is this the only way? I'd expect to have a more clean way, in my **Contest.php** perhaps? Looking forward to possible answers!

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. The Dynamic Page Cache respects max-age = 0, so there is no more clean way to disable it. Do you mean the [Internal Page Cache](https://www.drupal.org/docs/administering-a-drupal-site/internal-page-cache)? Only if you've enabled this module you would need the additional kill switch. Or do you mean the response headers to control the browser cache?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry, I mean both internal page cache as Internal Dynamic Page Cache. Let's consider both modules to be enabled. I was just wondering if there is a more OO way to define the caching of the custom entity detail pages.

Comment: There are more things unclear. Your code is checking for a bundle, but it seems like you want to check `getEntityTypeId()`. If this is the case you could add the option `no_cache: TRUE` to the entity routes (route_provider in your entity class **Contest**).

Comment: Correct answer below was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was just wondering if there is a more OO way to define the caching
> of the custom entity detail pages.

This would be extending the route provider you are using now (DefaultHtmlRouteProvider or AdminHtmlRouteProvider), specifying it in the custom entity class

```
*     "route_provider" = {
*       "html" = "Drupal\mymodule\MyEntityRouteProvider",
*     },
```

and overriding `getCanonicalRoute` to add the no_cache option:

```
protected function getCanonicalRoute(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  $route = parent::getCanonicalRoute($entity_type);
  $route->setOption('no_cache', TRUE);
  return $route;
}
```

Comment: Great. I did not know this. Thanks.